# Should I Use Business Connectivity Services or Not in This Specific Scenario

Tags: bcs, people-search

I'm currently working on a SharePoint Standard 2010 project.

I would have preferred to use the User Profile Service to sync with AD to populate employee details, but our AD doesn't have much information.

But we have the employee list stored in a SQL Server table so I'm thinking of using BCS.

My question is if I use BCS to populate the employee list will users be able to search employee details if I use the "Basic Search Center Template" or will I have to use "SharePoint Enterprise Search in SharePoint Server 2010"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom bcs synchronization connection, that consume data from sql table and map it to user profile properties. This procedure involves creating bcs solution, adding Business DataCatalog Connection to synchronization connections, and setting up mapping between bcs rows and user profile properties. If you map it to standard properties, they should appear in any search.

Comment: Thanks Kai.
If i create ECTs(External Content Types) in sharepoint designer and then use it to populate a list.Will this appear in search?

Comment: I am not 100%, but it should. Give it a try.

Comment: ok one more question here.
Is there a way i can use User Profile service to use data from external source like from Sql server tables?
Cheers and thanks alot

Comment: Yes, you can. You should create bcs model, and then add new synchronization connection under user profile service application. Next step is to setup mappings between your bcs elements (such as Name, Job title, location, etc) and profile properties. Take a look at [this](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/everything-you-need-to-know-about-bdc-part-6-of-8) article, it describes some basic concepts.

Comment: Thanks the article was about BDC not BCS i'm on SP 2010

Comment: Situation in 2010 is mostly the same, but I am not found any good article about it, sorry :(